# Is "$\mathrm E[X'X]$ has rank $k$" the assumption of no multicollinearity?

Tags: multicollinearity, matrix

My lecturer wrote this on the board:

> Assume $\mathrm E[X'X]=Q$ has rank $k$, where $X$ is the data matrix and $k$ is the number of independent variables.

I asked her if that is the assumption of no multicollinearity, and she said, "No."
I said that if one of the variables are a linear combination of the others, the rank will be less than $k$.
She responded that the rank will still be $k$ if there is collinearity.

Who is right?

Comment: "Multicollinearity" does not mean "one or more of the variables are linear combinations of other variables", it just means the columns of $X$ are not orthogonal, so the answer would be "No."  In your case, $Q$ having non-zero off-diagonal elements corresponds to multicollinearity, but obviously doesn't imply that $Q$ is rank-deficient.

Comment: I disagree, but even if you are right, the rank will be less than $k$.

Comment: Sure, if one is an exact linear combination of the others, the rank will be less than $k$, but that's the most extreme form of multicollinearity, known as "perfect multicollinearity".  Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity for support of my statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to distinguish multicollinearity in general from perfect multicollinearity. The introduction to the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity) handles that distinction pretty well.

Your lecturer presumably was talking about multicollinearity other than perfect multicollinearity. With perfect multicollinearity the design matrix $X$ necessarily has less than full rank. In practice, this can arise from a data-handling error in which the same predictor is represented in the design matrix as two or more exactly linearly dependent predictors.*

Particularly with large data sets, what's more typically going on is that many of the predictors have close but not perfect linear relations among them. So there is multicollinearity but not perfect multicollinearity. That's the more usual type of multicollinearity in practice.

In that case the design matrix will still have full rank (provided there aren't more predictors than observations), but its [matrix condition number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number#Matrices) might be so high that it is *close to* not having full rank. Then there will at best be large variance in estimates of coeffficients of correlated predictors and there could even be numerical analysis problems in solving the equations.

---

*You could in principle have more complicated exact linear relations among predictors accidentally leading to perfect multicollinearity, but such situations are harder to envision. In contrast, accidentally entering the same predictor twice can be all too easy if, say, you're in a rush.